# Storing data from Azure Face API - Python

Tags: python, database, azure, dataframe, twitter

I am constructing a twitter database and would like to record some demographic data based on profile pictures. I decided to do this using Microsoft's Face API, but I am new to Python and coding in general, is there a way to:

1. Extract and save the age and gender data into the same or separate data frame.
2. Construct a list of only unique twitter handles, based on my data, so that I don't waste my daily call limit on Azure.
3. Append the data so that I have the age and gender of each person, stored next to their unique twitter handle.

The twitter data is stored in the format:

'timestamp', 'id', 'text', 'user', 'replies', 'retweets', 'likes'

I am also open to less other suggestions.

P.S.

Is the Python demo for Face broken, because it won't run with the default code?

Comment: What you're trying to do here is against Twitter developer policy (see https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/more-on-restricted-use-cases.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wide, you should keep your questions focused on particular problem. Let me answer to part one:

You should use the SDK:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/

And you have some samples here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-python-sdk-samples/blob/master/samples/vision/face_samples.py

After that, storing and building a DB is a different question that I suggest humbly you ask separately once you have specific questions after your got the data you like.